# How can I move an object in an "infinity" or "figure 8" trajectory?

Tags: mathematics, movement, trajectory

When I want to move object around point I do:

```
    point.x *= cosf(timer.timeElapsed);
    point.y *= sinf(timer.timeElapsed);
```

How to make point move on eight or infinity sign trajectory?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Some possibilities:

[Lemniscate of Bernoulli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate_of_Bernoulli)

[Lemniscate of Gerono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate_of_Gerono)

[Lemniscate of Booth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate_of_Booth)

[Watt's curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watt%27s_curve)

Comment: Answers should be self-contained, external links may die some day and would render this answer useless. You should quote the important bits from the links you've provided.

Answer (score 69):

As Marton notes, there are several "figure of eight" curves that might fit your needs.  Perhaps the simplest is the [lemniscate of Gerono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate_of_Gerono), which has the parametrization:

```
x = cos(t);
y = sin(2*t) / 2;
```

and looks like this:

[image: Lemniscate of Gerono animation]

However, the [lemniscate of Bernoulli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate_of_Bernoulli) may be visually more pleasing; it has a parametrization very similar to the lemniscate of Gerono, except that both axes are scaled by a factor of `1/(sin(t)^2 + 1) = 2/(3 - cos(2*t))`:

```
scale = 2 / (3 - cos(2*t));
x = scale * cos(t);
y = scale * sin(2*t) / 2;
```

It looks like this:

[image: Lemniscate of Bernoulli animation]

(Animations made with Maple 13, compressed with GIFsicle.)

Comment: Thank you, everybody, for your support, which has earned me [my first gold badge](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/badges/39/populist?userid=9280) here on gamedev! :-)

Comment: +1 for not only posting the links, but also the formulas and graphics ( with sources ).

Comment: As is, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

I randomly found another one using this formula:

$$x^2 = y^2 + 0.1x^{2.8}$$

As plotted [by Wolfram Alpha](http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2+%3D+y%5E2+%2B+0.1x%5E2.8):

[image: half of an infinity symbol]

Comment: Unlike the other answers, this one is currently not presented in parametric form that lets us easily step the position forward over time `t`. I'd recommend including a description of how you would use this formula to position a moving object over time.

Answer (score -3):

## $$((x+1)^2+y^2)((x-1)^2+y^2)=1$$

[image: half of an infinity symbol]

## The product of the distances from any point on that curve to (-1, 0) and to (1,0) is constant and equals to 1.

Comment: This answer provides a formula modelling such a curve, but not a method to "move an object" in such a way that it follows that curve. Please consider elaborating on the answer to indicate how you would use this math to move an object in a game.