# How can I move and rotate an object in an “infinity” or “figure 8” trajectory?

Tags: mathematics, graphics, software-engineering, trajectory

I know that the easiest way to move an object with the figure 8 trajectory is:

```
x = cos(t);
y = sin(2*t) / 2;
```

but I just don't know how to rotate it, lets says with a new variable r as rotation, how do I merge it into the above formula ?
can anyone please advise me on what is the simplest and cheapest way/formula to move and rotate the figure 8 trajectory ?

ref:[How can I move an object in an "infinity" or "figure 8" trajectory?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/43691/how-can-i-move-an-object-in-an-infinity-or-figure-8-trajectory)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object should point in the direction of the derivative, which is `[-sin(t), cos(2t)]`. Its angle is `atan2(cos(2t), -sin(t))`.

Edit: OP is apparently asking how to rotate the "trajectory," not the object itself.

To rotate the figure, choose an angle, `θ`, in radians, that you'd like the trajectory to be rotated. The position along this rotated figure is:

```
x = cos(θ) * cos(t) - sin(θ) * sin(2t)/2
y = sin(θ) * cos(t) + cos(θ) * sin(2t)/2
```

Comment: so how would I modify the formula to get a rotated figure of 8 ?

Comment: That is a completely different question than the one I answered. I'll edit my answer with a solution to this question.